# netbeans ide 8.2 string cannot be converted to char error

Tags: java, netbeans

soy principiante en programacion y tengo este problema. segun el curso online que estoy haciendo el programa es el siguiente (y funciona). pero cuando lo ingreso yo me muestra el error "string cannot be converted to char". 
que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias!

```
char nota = "2" ;        (aqui el error "string cannot be converted to char")

 switch (nota){

   case '5' :

   System.out.println ("suficiente");

   break;

   case '6':

   System.out.println ("bien");

   break;

default:

   System.out.println ("suspendido");
```

Comment: Estás usando comillas dobles `nota =  "2"` y deben ser simples `nota =  '2'`

Comment: muchas gracias! solucionado!